# How to test whether a ref struct method is throwing an exception using xUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit, ref-struct

I'm new to xUnit, but, as far as I know, the standard way of checking whether something throws an exception is to use `Assert.Throws<T>` or `Assert.ThrowsAny<T>` methods.

But these methods expect an Action as parameter; and ref structs can't be "embedded" in lambdas.

So, how does one test whether a given method of a ref struct is throwing?
Example of code that *doesn't* work:

```
[Fact]
public void HelpMe() {
    var pls = new Span<byte>();
    Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => {
        plsExplode = pls[-1];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ref struct can't be *captured* in a lambda expression, but you can still *use* it in a lambda expression - you just need to declare the variable there, so that it's never a field within a non-ref-struct.

For example, this compiles and succeeds:

```
[Fact]
public void HelpMe()
{
    Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => {
        var pls = new Span<byte>();
        var plsExplode = pls[-1];
    });
}
```

Now I'll be the first to admit that this isn't ideal: you really want to do the minimum amount of work possible within the action, so that you only pass if the expected piece of code fails.

Using `Assert.Throws` helps there, so that only the expected exception results in a pass. Additionally, you could capture a `bool` which is changed just before the throwing part, then check that you'd got that far:

```
[Fact]
public void HelpMe()
{
    bool reachedThrowingPart = false;
    Assert.Throws<IndexOutOfRangeException>(() =>
    {
        var span = new Span<byte>();
        reachedThrowingPart = true;
        var ignored = span[-1];
    });
    Assert.True(reachedThrowingPart);
}
```

It's all significantly wordier than it would be if it weren't for ref struct restrictions, but they're understandable...

Comment: @Trauer: See the update; you can tigthen it up a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own `Assert.Throws` that passes the `ref struct` through a parameter to avoid capturing it in a closure.

```cs
using System;
using Xunit;

public ref struct RefStruct1
{
    public void MethodThatThrows(int x) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class Test1
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(0)]
    [InlineData(int.MaxValue)]
    public void MethodThatThrows_Always_ThrowsNotImplementedException(int x)
    {
        var refStruct1 = new RefStruct1();

        AssertThrows<NotImplementedException>(ref refStruct1, (ref RefStruct1 rs1) => rs1.MethodThatThrows(x));
    }

    private delegate void RefStruct1Action(ref RefStruct1 rs1);

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    private static T AssertThrows<T>(ref RefStruct1 rs1, RefStruct1Action action)
        where T : Exception
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        try
        {
            action(ref rs1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() == typeof(T))
                return (T)ex;

            throw new Xunit.Sdk.ThrowsException(typeof(T), ex);
        }

        throw new Xunit.Sdk.ThrowsException(typeof(T));
    }
}
```